# JPA @NamedQuery CAST number to text

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring & Hibernate with Postgres.

I have the following @NamedQuery:

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "PowWowJournalHeaderEntity.findAllLike", query = "select object(o) from PowWowJournalHeader o where CAST(o.ticketNumber AS TEXT) like ?1"),
```

as you can see, I am trying to cast a number (Long) to text to do a LIKE.

```
CAST(o.ticketNumber AS TEXT) like ?1
```

However, it gets an error.

**Question**

How do you do a text comparison with a number using a @Namedquery in Hibernate/JPA?

More info:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure cast is supported by JPQL? HQL supports it, maybe try org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery instead of the JPA NamedQuery annotation.

Comment: You can ignore the error/warning messages of IntelliJ. Hibernate supports that, so this is fine.